# Lock down Mozilla Firefox for Citrix

Tags: group-policy, firefox

We have a requirement to publish a web application through Citrix, but the application works only with Mozilla Firefox. We are looking for a way to disable the below 4 things.

1. Disable the prompt to set Firefox as default browser
2. Disable the prompt to import all settings from internet explorer. But the setting should not import.
3. Disable automatic Update.
4. Disable or hide the address bar in order to force the user to use Firefox only for the predefined website.

We have the GPO ADMX files from Firefox and we are planning to set the configurations by Group Policy. We assume that this this approach can be done using Firefox Preference GPO. Any one know the correct method to configure Firefox Preferences using GPO and configure the above 4 settings as well.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is setting: `"browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser" = false`
2. In browser folder under Firefox installation create file (UTF8 without BOM) with content:

   `[XRE]
   EnableProfileMigrator=false`
3. There is settings:
   `"app.update.enabled" = false
   "app.update.auto" = false
   "app.update.mode" = 0
   "app.update.service.enabled" = false`
4. This is only possible through the addon, or browser customization.

It may also be useful documentation from Mozilla about [Firefox deployment in the enterprise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment).

> Any one know the correct method to configure Firefox Preferences using
>   GPO

This [GPO module](https://mozillagpo.sourceforge.io/) works fine. It has page at [sourceforge with additional documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/mozillagpo/wiki/Home/).

But not all can be done by changing user preferences. For additional customization (unfortunately not controlled through GPO), I recommend you look closely to [Mike's Kaply product CCK2](https://mike.kaply.com/cck2/)

P.S. Unfortunately, you have chosen one of the most difficult to configure browsers for the enterprise.